# Are summations a function?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I am taking a finance course and the Present Value relation got me thinking. Using a continuous compounding convention for a collection of cash flows, this is commonly expressed as

$\text{PV} = \sum_{i=0}^N c_i\text{exp}(-rt_i)$,

where $c$ is the cashflow size, $t$ is the cashflow date and $r$ is the interest rate.

My TLDR question is: Is PV a function? Of what? Two sets of real numbers and a further real number?

As a non-mathematician, my intuition is that this is a function of $r$ and two sets $T$ and $C$ where $t \in T$ and $c \in C$. However, I am not sure if it makes any mathematical sense that these sets are the variables (or input) of the function.

For a single cashflow, I believe that the present value

$\text{PV} = c \, \text{exp}(-rt)$

*is* indeed a function of $t$, $c$ and $r$ that could be expressed as $\text{PV}(t,c,r)$.

Can this be extended to the multicashflow case simply replacing $t$ and $c$ for the sets $T$ and $C$ such that $\text{PV}(T,C,r)$ is a function?

The key issue for me is the summation. I am not sure if summing over $i$ implies that the different $t_i$'s and $c_i$'s are considered different variables or not.

I apologise if I am asking a ridiculous question. I have not taken any real analysis classes.

Comment: Your sum is a function of $N,\{c_i\}, \{t_i\}$ and $r$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. Given $N=|\{c_i\}|=|\{t_i\}|$ isn't it redundant to say the summation is a function of $N$?

Comment: $N$ can be changed.  If, say, you have lots of $c's, t's$ then you can sum over some  portions of them.  This is done in finance all the time.

Comment: But, sure.  If somehow you know that the summation window will never change, then you don't need to think of $N$ as a variable.

Comment: @lulu I see, thank you!

Comment: summation is something which eats a discrete funciton and a set and gives you a number.. similar to how integration eats a set and a contiinous function and gives you a number

Comment: @Buraian thanks. That makes sense

Comment: I think you have to treat $T$ and $C$ as sequences rather than simple sets of data, because sets do not define a "first element", yet you definitely need to pair up the first $t$ with the first $c.$ If you treat $T$ and $C$ as finite sequences with sufficient structure that you can define a length function on them, that is, function $L$ over finite sequences so that $L(T)$ is the length of $T$, and other functions such as the $i$th member of a sequence, I think you can define $PV(T,C,r)$ as a function.

Comment: @DavidK That makes sense, thanks. I was thinking PV could be a function of a set containing subsets $\{c_i, t_i\} \for i \in 1, ..., N$ but sequences are closer to what I was describing in the post. By length $L(T)$ what do you mean? Is this equivalent to cardinality/size?

Comment: "Length" would be the number of terms in the sequence. You could also say cardinality or size. Actually a set of *ordered pairs* $(c_i,t_i)$ would be a good alternative, assuming all times are unique. The things to watch out for when calling things "sets" are that sets have no sense of sequence and no capability of repetition, whereas the input to a PV requires you to know which payment was on which date, there can be multiple payments of the same amount, and a payment of $1$ in year $2$ is definitely not equivalent to a payment of $2$ in year $1.$

Comment: If you use ordered pairs, however, the notation $PV(T,C,r)$ doesn't quite fit that input because the amounts and times are all mixed together in one set rather than all times in an object named $T$ and all amounts in an object named $C$.